# Detect if user has been redirected from different domain

Tags: javascript, redirect, browser, load-balancing

I'm redirecting my user from e.g. olddomain.com to newdomain.com.

If the user goes directly to newdomain.com I'm just displaying the page, but if the user was redirected from olddomain.com, then after redirecting and displaying page I want to additionally display some modal to user (saying "hey, we just changed our name to newdomain"). Is it possible to detect in JavaScript if the user was redirected so that I can display the message?

I believe it's impossible to do with DNS redirect, but is it possible using load-balancer redirection (that would be ideal) or in JS by changing `window.location`?

Comment: You can set referer in headers.

Comment: Did you try with `document.referrer`?

Comment: Could be as simple as the redirect url includes a query string and you check for it but if you can not adjust it, you need to rely on it.